# How does one understand the second and third triad in Hegels Logic?

Tags: logic, hegel, ancient-philosophy

The first dialectical triad in Hegels *Logic* and put in a mathematical form is

> Being + Nothing = Becoming

Although a strange sum, I find this understandable. His second dialectical triad takes the form:

> Quality + Quantity = Measure

And then

> Measure + Measureless = Essence

How should one understand these two dialectical triads? Quantity on the face of it seems analogous to Measure.

Is Quantity to be thought of as pure abstract quantity and then Measure to be a kind of  quantifiable quality?

Essence, as far as I understand it, is of Ancient Greek provenance and modified by Medieval Scholastic philosophy. How does the ancient or traditional understanding of Essence fit into Hegels schema?

Comment: W.T. Stace, The Philosophy of Hegel, Dover, beginning at around page 120. Internet Archive. I don't know if you are aware of this book.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/W.T.StaceThePhilosophyOfHegelDoverPress1955  Essence begins at page 175.

Comment: @Gordan: Thanks for the ref. I haven't come across this book before. I've just read the SEP entry on Hegels Dialectics and that cleared up a number of confusions that I had, especially with his pre-modern notion of logic. He calls something a logic when it has an aspect of necessity, which to me, seems apt. Though it raises the question, whether physical necessity is then a form of logic. If one dispenses with Lewises possible worlds - which seems only apt only from the perspective of formal logic - it seems viable. Physicists, then, are searching for Natures logic and not the nature of logic.

Comment: I'd also add that what interests me is that Hegels logic is dynamic, it changes and this has interesting parallels with the point of view argued for by Lee Smolin in his book *Time Reborn*, where he argues that natures laws change in time. So Natures logic would be dynamic. Hegel is also interesting from the perspective of holism and emergence since higher laws emerge from his logic, but aren't reducible to lower logical laws, each level has an irreducible novelty.

Comment: I'm just leafing through Staces book now. It looks pretty interesting.

Comment: Hegel is one of my favorites, extremely helpful in the actual living and understanding of life and the world, the way things "move",  though I am guilty of appropriating from him what I need and ignoring the rest. I can't keep him all in my mind at one time. I enjoy Stace because I can understand him.  You might know about the Prof. Bernstein tapes (transcripts) on the Phenomenology. http://www.bernsteintapes.com/

Comment: @Gordan: I think Stace is enough for me at present :), but thanks for the tip. I like Hegels discussion on art & religion, I think he has some useful things to say there and the relationship between them. I tend to think of secularised art as being a bit unmoored. Yes, poor us who try to assimilate what others have thought up and thought through - the question I have is how on earth did they find the time for all that thinking, writing and speaking. Perhaps because they lived in a slower time.